# How do i know when redux store is updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Or in other words, how do i know when a action that's dispatched is complete?

I have a webapp where I'd update the redux store through dispatches on user input. If i push the redux store's state to the server right after dispatching, the server does not have the most updated info. I need to wait for the action to complete prior to pushing to server, hence the question.

**EDIT**
Based on markerikson's answer I solved it. I thought dispatch was called asynchronously but the execution of the group of dispatched actions happened synchronously. That's wrong and mark's right. My issue was the the update server call was made in a component and it pushes to server a prop that needed to be updated by redux-store. That updating of the prop didn't happen fast enough.

Comment: If you are using redux saga you can just fire another action that the reducers listen and make required changes. And could pass this data as props from above.

Comment: @user93 I'll have to check out redux saga sometime. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispatching is entirely synchronous, unless altered by a middleware.  So, as soon as the call to `dispatch()` returns, the store state has been updated and all subscribers have been notified.

If you need to wait for some async behavior to complete, you can write a thunk that returns a promise, and chain off that when you dispatch:

```
function someThunkReturningAPromise() {
   return (dispatch) => {
      const promise = myAjaxLib.fetchData().then(response => {
          dispatch(loadData(response.data));
      });

      return promise;
   } 
}

dispatch(someThunkReturningAPromise()).then( () => {  });
```

Comment: I thought dispatch was called asynchronously but the execution of the group of dispatched actions happened synchronously. That's wrong and you're right. My issue was the the update server call was made in a component and it pushes to server a prop that needed to be updated by redux-store. That updating of the prop didn't happen fast enough. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot check for an updated prop value right after dispatching an action, because React hasn't had a chance to actually execute the re-render cycle yet.  It's very similar to not being able to check for an updated `this.state` value right after calling `this.setState()`, because `setState()` is called async, and the re-render process is async as well.

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the question, but for the people who got here based on the question title - take a look into:

```
store.subscribe()
store.getState()
```

where 'store' is a reference to your redux store.

```
store.subscribe(() => {
    const newState = store.getState();
    // check out your updated state
});
```

the code above would run anytime there is an update to the redux state